# Debugging varying command line parameters with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, debugging, m2e

I have a Java project/program in eclipse that I can load up and run, plus modify the command line parameters successfully. This program only takes a few seconds to run and I would like to test it with a variety of command line parameter configurations. Is there a way I can configure eclipse to run something like the following bash script after I hit the debug button a single time?

```
java Classify -mode train -algorithm majority -model_file outputModelEvenOdd -data ./Homework1Data/bio/bio.train
java Classify -mode test -model_file outputModelEvenOdd -data ./Homework1Data/bio/bio.dev -predictions_file bioPredictionsEvenOdd

echo "**finance data**"
java Classify -mode train -algorithm majority -model_file outputModelEvenOdd -data ./Homework1Data/finance/finance.train
java Classify -mode test -model_file outputModelEvenOdd -data ./Homework1Data/finance/finance.dev -predictions_file financePredictionsEvenOdd

echo "**speech data**"
java Classify -mode train -algorithm majority -model_file outputModelEvenOdd -data ./Homework1Data/speech/speech.train
java Classify -mode test -model_file outputModelEvenOdd -data ./Homework1Data/speech/speech.dev -predictions_file speechPredictionsEvenOdd

echo "**synthetic easy data**"
java Classify -mode train -algorithm majority -model_file outputModelEvenOdd -data ./Homework1Data/synthetic/easy.train
java Classify -mode test -model_file outputModelEvenOdd -data ./Homework1Data/synthetic/easy.dev -predictions_file syntheticEasyEvenOdd

echo "**synthetic hard data**"
java Classify -mode train -algorithm majority -model_file outputModelEvenOdd -data ./Homework1Data/synthetic/hard.train
java Classify -mode test -model_file outputModelEvenOdd -data ./Homework1Data/synthetic/hard.dev -predictions_file syntheticHardEvenOdd

echo "**vision data**"
java Classify -mode train -algorithm majority -model_file outputModelEvenOdd -data ./Homework1Data/vision/vision.train
java Classify -mode test -model_file outputModelEvenOdd -data ./Homework1Data/vision/vision.dev -predictions_file visionEvenOdd
```

I'd like breakpoints and the visual debugger to work between runs. As a side note I'm also using the maven eclipse plugin (I think m2e), in case that has such capabilities.

I know I can alternatively modify my program to load all instances from a single file containing parameters for all the situations, but if Eclipse has a facility for this style of testing I'd like to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse does not have a built-in facility for that.

Doing test runs like that can be implemented with a unit test framework such as [JUnit](http://junit.org/), and Eclipse has built-in support for running JUnit, so you don't even have to download a JUnit jar file.

You might still want to download a JUnit jar file for running the same tests outside of Eclipse, e.g. using Ant or Gradle, or if you want to use a different version of JUnit than the one shipped with Eclipse.

**Example**

```
public class ClassifyTest {
    @Test
    public void trainAndTestBio() {
        Classify.main(new String[] {
            "-mode",       "train",
            "-algorithm",  "majority",
            "-model_file", "outputModelEvenOdd",
            "-data",       "./Homework1Data/bio/bio.train"
        });
        Classify.main(new String[] {
            "-mode",             "test",
            "-model_file",       "outputModelEvenOdd",
            "-data",             "./Homework1Data/bio/bio.dev",
            "-predictions_file", "bioPredictionsEvenOdd"
        });
    }
    @Test
    public void trainAndTestFinance() {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't mind using JUnit, could you possibly expand a bit on how to do that? So essentially I'd need to set up a unit test for that, perhaps if it is possible to call a class that has a main() from JUnit? If I can get to a working solution I'd be more than happy to accept your answer!

Comment: Go to the [JUnit website](http://junit.org/) and click the "[Getting started](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Getting-started)" link.